# creating new columns against each row in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a columnv1 which has some items and column, v2 which has some items. I want to create a column V3 that will have items present it v2 but not in v1. Need to perform this on large datasets having million of rows.

| vname | v1 | v2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| vendor1 | 123.45 | 24ab,bnhy,nbh234 |
| vendor | abc123,cfcbgg | cfcbgg,abcder |

I tried this code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('br.xlsx')
acpbr= df.v1.values.tolist()
vbr=df.v2.values.tolist()
diff = set(vbr) - set(acpbr)
```

I know the above code will print the result "diff" but I want to print value in a new column against each row; like the one below. Pl suggest. My question was not clear, hence edited it.

| vname | v1 | v2 | v3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| vendor1 | 123.45 | 24ab,bnhy,nbh234 | 24ab,bnhy,nbh234 |
| vendor | abc123,cfcbgg | cfcbgg,abcder | abcder |

Comment: So, do that in a function, and use `df['v3'] = df.apply(myfilter)`.

Comment: "*The above code is creating the result but not printing value in a new column against each row*" Can you explain what *specifically* in the code you've provided that you expect to modify the DataFrame at all?

Comment: your code only stores in  'diff' you are not creating a new column

Comment: yes,  I know it stores only diff, I edited my question .

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you want to split the elements in each row by ',' before taking the difference and applying to the new row, if you take the element as a whole its very easy (but I don't think that's what you want)

I am using list comprehension, splitting by ',' (make sure to do astype (str) on the columns before you apply the below logic if you have numbers),finding the difference and then joining back

df['v4'] = [','.join(np.setdiff1d(a.split(','),b.split(','))) for a,b in zip(df['v2'],df['v1'])]

I am using numpy's setdiff1d to find the difference between the two sets

```
     #astype str for numbers
     df['v1'] =df['v1'].astype(str)
     df['v4'] = [','.join(np.setdiff1d(a.split(','),b.split(','))) for a,b in zip(df['v2'],df['v1'])]
     #new modified code to work with the test case eliminates spaces following  a comma before comparison
     df['v4'] = [','.join(np.setdiff1d(a.split(','),b.split(','))) for a,b in zip(df['v2'].str.replace(r',\s+',',',regex=True),df['v1'].str.replace(r',\s+',',',regex=True))]
```

Output -
[sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7J4Fn.png)

Comment: I think the above code is correct but some of the cases are not giving desired results. for example: Under v1- I had NPD 021080 1190, 021080 1190 ; In v2, I had 101211, 021080 1190, NPD 021080 1190, 2961 . I applied the above logic after converting columns as str and getting these in  v4:  2961, NPD 021080 1190,101211.

Comment: I have modified the original code to include a regex that removes spaces following a comma (the reason why the match failed v2 npd has a space following the comma), there could be other such cases so just check them and eliminate them (for eg spaces after a comma or at the string start perhaps) , the modified code works with your test case